# How to do Jo Blow is viewing "XYZ" on mysite.com facebook updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, status

What is required for me to integrate automatic activity updates on a user's facebook status?

I frequently see things like "Joe Shmoe" is listening to Cornbread And Butter... by Carolina Chocolate D... on Spotify

I'd like to know what it takes to integrate this.

My suppositions:

I imagine the user has to "agree" to this.
The user has to either sign in with Facebook auth, or be signed in?
There is some kind of server-side script that runs when a page loads, or is this an ajax JS library. 
Does facebook offer some kind of api for this or JS library for this?

Also I work with Ruby on Rails, so please let me know if there's a gem that facilitates this.

Any info appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/
This is the documentation for the new Open Graph features which include low friction publishing of structured data